# if statement is not returning expected result Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement, alert, prompt

I wrote a small script after learning a bit about the object constructor and I wanted to take it a step further with this code, but the `if statement` isn't behaving as expected... All I want to know is why? I understand this kind of script isn't a normal thing in Javascript... but I believe that the `===` is evaluating to `true`, thus printing `dave` in the alert box, no matter what I enter, and not following through the `if statement` conditions.

```
var dave, jason, nick, get;

get = prompt('Input your Name', 'Name Here')


var Person = function (name, birthYear, job) {
    this.name = name;
    this.birthYear = birthYear;
    this.job = job;
};

dave = new Person('Dave', 1976, 'Showman');
jason = new Person('Jason', 1987, 'Novice');
nick = new Person('Nick', 1993, 'Cable-tech');


function printObj(object) {
    var output = '';
    for (var property in object) {
        output += property + ': ' + object[property] + '\n';
    }
    alert(output);
}

if (get.toLowerCase === 'dave'.toLowerCase) {
    printObj(dave);
} else if (get.toLowerCase === 'jason'.toLowerCase) {
    printObj(jason);
} else if (get.toLowerCase === 'nick'.toLowerCase) {
    printObj(nick);
} else {
    alert('Not a defined object')
}
```

Something else obvious I might be doing wrong is the comparison... but that's how it was explained to me in **javascript on freenode**, because at first that was my issue, which is still kind of it I suppose. I think I'm simply doing something obviously messy, appreciate any insight I receive, the **MDN** and **W3** only explain so much.

Comment: Isn't `.toLowerCase()` a function method? Could that be what's wrong?

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill yes. In fact on both sides of the === it is the same function so they are equal.

Comment: Well, my original idea was to use get === /dave/i but that didn't work. using toLowerCase was suggested in ##javascript to me.
I'm still very much on the novice level. That would cause it to print dave for any response input?

Comment: also, why would you `'everything in lower case'.toLowerCase()` if `everything in lower case` is already *in lower case*

Comment: As the 'get' is received from prompt, I was trying to account for Uppercase names being sent to 'get' which I found out is reserved in newer versions, and have currently changed to yourName

Answer (score 1):

`get.toLowerCase()` is a method, and should be invoked with the open and closed parenthesis. The way it is currently written is checking whether the method is equal to the same method on a different string instance.

```
if (get.toLowerCase() === 'dave') {
    printObj(dave);
} else if (get.toLowerCase() === 'jason') {
    printObj(jason);
} else if (get.toLowerCase() === 'nick') {
    printObj(nick);
} else {
    alert('Not a defined object')
}
```

Since you are comparing to a lowercase string, you don't need to call `toLowerCase()` on `'dave'`, `'jason'`, or `'nick'`. I think you may have meant to compare to the value stored in the variables `dave`, `jason`, and `nick`.

```
if (get.toLowerCase() === dave.name.toLowerCase()) {
    printObj(dave);
} else if (get.toLowerCase() === jason.name.toLowerCase()) {
    printObj(jason);
} else if (get.toLowerCase() === nick.name.toLowerCase()) {
    printObj(nick);
} else {
    alert('Not a defined object')
}
```

Last, you should not name a variable `get`. `get` is reserved in ES6 so as browser start to natively support it, your code will do some very odd things. I suggest something like `userInput`.

```
var dave, jason, nick, userInput;

userInput = prompt('Input your Name', 'Name Here')

//...other code...

if (userInput.toLowerCase() === dave.name.toLowerCase()) {
    printObj(dave);
} else if (userInput.toLowerCase() === jason.name.toLowerCase()) {
    printObj(jason);
} else if (userInput.toLowerCase() === nick.name.toLowerCase()) {
    printObj(nick);
} else {
    alert('Not a defined object')
}
```

Comment: Very helpful, let me adjust based on your suggestions, and see what my local instance yields me.  So basically I should compare it to the property that's already present rather than presenting my own string?

Comment: You can use your own string as well, I was just providing options

Comment: No no, it's very useful to have shortcuts/other paths pointed out.  But now I don't get printObj  called for any matching names. I only get the else alert. I think I'm just bad at javascript.

Comment: userInput.toLowerCase() === dave.name.toLowerCase() didn't work
but userInput.toLowerCase() === 'dave' did, and the script is working as intended now. Thank you for your help. Not sure why your suggestion didn't work though. I understand why it should work but not why it doesn't. I still have more to learn I guess.

Comment: Not sure. It works for me. Could be a simple typo somewhere on your side. JavaScript is fun like that :D Glad you got it working though. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

You are using the `.toLowerCase()` method the wrong way. Also, you are using the `get`

Your Code:

```
var dave, jason, nick, get;

get = prompt('Input your Name', 'Name Here')

// other code

if (get.toLowerCase === 'dave'.toLowerCase) {
    printObj(dave);
} else if (get.toLowerCase === 'jason'.toLowerCase) {
    printObj(jason);
} else if (get.toLowerCase === 'nick'.toLowerCase) {
    printObj(nick);
} else {
    alert('Not a defined object')
}
```

As you can see on your code your `.toLowerCase` method misses the `()`. And please do not use the `get` as a variable name because `get` is a keyword.

Try this:

```
var dave, jason, nick, inputValue;

inputValue = prompt('Input your Name', 'Name Here')

// other code

if (inputValue.toLowerCase() === 'dave'.toLowerCase()) {
    printObj(dave);
} else if (inputValue.toLowerCase() === 'jason'.toLowerCase()) {
    printObj(jason);
} else if (inputValue.toLowerCase() === 'nick'.toLowerCase()) {
    printObj(nick);
} else {
    alert('Not a defined object')
}
```

Also, if you are comparing an own defined comparison there's no need to add the `.toLowerCase()`. You actually want to compare the input value (which is an unknown format ei. upper case or lower case) to a lower case string value that you want to compared of.

Use this:

```
if (get.toLowerCase === 'dave')
```

instead of

```
if (get.toLowerCase === 'dave'.toLowerCase())
```

Comment: I have indeed ceased using get as a variable and have switched to  
`if (yourName.toLowerCase() === 'dave')`